# MySQL Server flashes on and off on mac. How to fix?

Tags: mac, mysql

I just downloaded the macOS 10.15 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive version of MySQL following https://youtu.be/TpOMn5_YIyw?t=305.

[But the server just flashes green for a second and then back to red when I click start.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj7Of.png)

It will flash intermittently to green and then back to red. In the terminal, I will type

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

and it returns

```
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Eileens-MacBook-Air.local.pid).
```

The result is the same when I type

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart

or 

sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

Not sure how to fix this. Not sure if this matters, but

- my mac also recently updated to the Catalina OS
- I installed mysql twice bc I'm a noob and thought the first time it didn't work because I thought you were supposed to find it in the launch page and not system preferences.

I have minimal coding background so this is all very new to me. Very much appreciate the help since google and youtube hasn't given much help.

Comment: You need to investigate the log files.

Comment: Did you check whenever the pid file exists? Did you check that not other mysql instance is running?